# How to embed a URL in robot framework's log file

Tags: python, robotframework

In robot framework I am loading a library as keywords.

Those keywords are methods in the library.

I know that I can send information directly to the Robot Framework Log file with a simple print statement.

But when my method creates a file, in the same directory as the Log file, how can I create a link to it in the log file?

Example:

Robot Framework file:

```
| *Setting* |
| Library | Testtools
| *Test Case* |
|                   | LogMe
```

Library file: TestTools.py

```
def LogMe(self):
    file = open('testfile.txt', 'w+')
    file.write("Line of text")
    file.close()
    print "The test file is found at http://testfile.txt"   #This line is where I need help
```

I need to know how to put a link to my freshly created file in the log that robot framework will create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be very simple.  Just by adding *HTML* to the printed string, robot framework will treat it as preformatted text.

All I need to do is change the last line of my code to this:

```
print "*HTML* The test file is found at <a href=testfile.txt>this location</a>"
```

And it all works.

Yah!